# OAuth 2.0 (Oct 1st) and Encrypted Access Token

Tags: facebook, migration, oauth-2.0

I am trying to get clarity on whether our app will be able to connect after Oct 1st.

If I enable the Encrypted Access Token migration (via the advanced settings menu in the Facebook Developers app) and my site can still connect, does that mean that it will still work on October 2nd?

The description of that migration is:
"Enabling confirms that your app is migrated to OAuth 2.0 and accepts an encrypted access token."

Comment: Also, wouldn't the "Remove Deprecated APIs" migration also rule out authentication methods that won't work after Oct 1?

Comment: Worth noting: I am not using the oauth: true parameter in my call to FB.init.  Therefore, unless I am wholly confused, I am not using OAuth 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of this https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/561/ developer blog post, you should be fine. The only setting (as far as I can tell) that they are going to force is "Upgrade to Requests 2.0".

You will also need to add a "Secure Canvas URL" and a "Secure Page Tab URL", if you haven't already.

Comment: from that page:  Using the latest SDKs (the JavaScript SDK with the oauth:true parameter and the PHP SDK v.3.1.1).  Our friend above said he was not using oauth:true, so his session variables from facebook may move around, causing breakage.